# System Crash, Usually happens when I open an elementaryOS app

Tags: applications

elementaryOS will freeze and hang forever when I open Videos, System Settings, and sometimes App Center. I can move the cursor but interaction beyond moving the cursor does not apparently do anything.

OS: elementaryOS 0.41 Loki
Hardware: Intel i5, Nvidia GTX 960 M, Solid State Drive

```
Apr 16 00:06:54 michael-N170RD1 anacron[971]: Job `cron.daily' terminated
Apr 16 00:06:54 michael-N170RD1 anacron[971]: Normal exit (1 job run)
Apr 16 00:06:57 michael-N170RD1 gnome-session[1133]: (process:1427): indicator-sound-WARNING **: accounts-service-access.vala:218: unable to sync volume 0.773575 to AccountsService: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such interface 'com.ubuntu.AccountsService.Sound'
Apr 16 00:06:58 michael-N170RD1 gnome-session[1133]: (process:1427): indicator-sound-WARNING **: accounts-service-access.vala:218: unable to sync volume 0.886780 to AccountsService: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such interface 'com.ubuntu.AccountsService.Sound'
Apr 16 00:12:02 michael-N170RD1 kernel: [  618.327007] usb 2-5: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Apr 16 00:12:02 michael-N170RD1 udisksd[1336]: Error performing housekeeping for drive /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/ST1000LM024_HN_M101MBB_S318J9BF202682: Error updating SMART data: Error sending ATA command CHECK POWER MODE: Unexpected sense data returned:#0120000: 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00    ................#0120010: 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00    ................#012 (g-io-error-quark, 0)
Apr 16 00:16:58 michael-N170RD1 systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
Apr 16 00:16:58 michael-N170RD1 systemd-tmpfiles[4438]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/var.conf:14] Duplicate line for path "/var/log", ignoring.
Apr 16 00:16:58 michael-N170RD1 systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Apr 16 00:17:01 michael-N170RD1 CRON[4441]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Apr 16 00:18:08 michael-N170RD1 org.gnome.zeitgeist.SimpleIndexer[1205]: ** (zeitgeist-fts:1519): WARNING **: Unable to get info on application://synapse.desktop
Apr 16 00:18:08 michael-N170RD1 gnome-session[1133]: Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"
Apr 16 00:18:08 michael-N170RD1 gnome-session[1133]: (keepassx:4448): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
```

Comment: There does not seem to be any crash in your syslog, but there does seem to be an issue with your USB disk, do you have another you can try?

Comment: Oh that's interesting. I think that it might be trying to probe my USB mouse. (Corsair Harpoon RGB, iirc)

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt-get upgrade` # solved my problems, thanks to everyone who looked at my problem.